# how to display message on textview in my application but not display on messagebox

Tags: java, android, sms

In my application any particular phone number send sms to my app that sms display on my application textview but not display on message box. Now I got sms on textview in my app as well as message box
problem

1] when I close my app that sms not display on textview

2] sms not display on message box.

3] when sms will come from particular no then how to blink (light) my app so users can understand 
some message come in my application.

```
    TextView in MainActivity.java that sms display on textview.
        MainActivity.java
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            String SENT="SMS_SENT";
            //String SENT =“SMS_SENT”;
            String DELIVERED="SMS_DELIVERED";
            PendingIntent sentPI, deliveredPI;
            BroadcastReceiver smsSentReceiver, smsDeliveredReceiver;
            IntentFilter intentFilter;
            private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //---display the SMS received in the TextView---
            TextView SMSes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            SMSes.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("sms"));

            }
            };
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                        new Intent(SENT), 0);
                        deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
                        //---intent to filter for SMS messages received---
                        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                        //intentFilter.addAction(“SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION”);
                        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEVIED_ACTION");
            }
            @Override
            public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            //---register the receiver---
            registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
            //---create the BroadcastReceiver when the SMS is sent---
            smsSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SMS Sent",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Genric Failure",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"NO Service",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"NULL PDU",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"radio off",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
            }
            }
            };

            smsDeliveredReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"sms delivered",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"sms not delivered",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
                }
                }


                };
                //---register the two BroadcastReceivers---
                registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
                registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
                }
            @Override
            public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            //---unregister the receiver---
            unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
            //---unregister the two BroadcastReceivers---
            unregisterReceiver(smsSentReceiver);
            unregisterReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver);
            }

            public void onClick(View v) {
            sendSMS("5556","Hello my friend");
                //sendSMS(“5556”, “Hello my friends!”);
            }
            public void onSMSIntentClick (View v) {
            Intent i = new
            Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.putExtra("address","1234567890");

            i.putExtra("sms_body","hello my friend!");
            i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            startActivity(i);
            }
            //—-sends an SMS message to another device—-
            private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
            {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
            }
        }

        SMSReceiver.java

        @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //---get the SMS message passed in---
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
                String str = "SMS From";
                if (bundle != null)
                {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                if(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals("9819861968")) {

                    //---get the sender address/phone number---
                    str += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    str +=":\n";
                    }
                    //---get the message body---

                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                this.abortBroadcast();

                    }
                    //---display the new SMS message---
                    Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("SMSReceiver", str);
                    //---send a broadcast intent to update the SMS received in the activity---
                    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                    broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEVIED_ACTION");
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
                    context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                        }
                }

manifest.xml
<receiver android:name="com.example.smsactivity.SMSReceiver">   
         <intent-filter>
         <action 
         android:priority="1000"
        android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

 </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

In my project how to display sms on textview when my application also close but that sms not display on messagebox.when any particular no send sms to me so only that no sms display on textview 
above coding all sms display on my application when my application is open as well as sms display on message box.
how to my application blink when sms come on my application

Comment: your question is unclear.

Comment: Your question doesn't need to be in perfect English, but this is not understandable.

Comment: 1] sms not display on messagebox

Comment: 1] sms not display on message box  2]particular sms display on my application(above coding all sms display on my textview) 3]when sms is coming than my application is light so user understand

Comment: @andi You can edit your post with the edit link underneath it: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27351611/edit

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not very clear but What I got your 3rd point you wanted to blink the notification light.
So here is the code for notification light.

```
private void RedFlashLight()
    {
    NotificationManager nm = ( NotificationManager ) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    Notification notif = new Notification();
    notif.ledARGB = 0xFFff0000;
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notif.ledOnMS = 100; 
    notif.ledOffMS = 100; 
    nm.notify(LED_NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
    }
```